# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

i have the following code and i am using sherlockfragments.

```
 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="450px"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and i am getting error:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: is this the whole xml layout file? If not could You please post the complete one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved
Thanks to all for your suggestions.

```
<Meta> Tag should be in <Application> Tag.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the correct answer, but try to put your fragment inside a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), it may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the getActivity()..

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

just try with change by:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

It did worked for me ...hope it would do for you also

Answer (score 1):

try yo use this:

```
private GoogleMap MAP;  

FragmentManager myFM = getSupportFragmentManager();  
       SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) myFM  
                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

MAP = myMAPF.getMap();
```

Also you have to change it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="450px"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="450px"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```